# Place div below all div's

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the position of text in Wordpress plugin. All I want to do is move text to the bottom of main div. I've tried `position: absolute;` `position:fixed` and also `clear:both` but nothing.
Here's my html stucture:

```
<div class="wc-restaurant-menu-product" data-product-id="1" data-order-type="lightbox" data- quantity="1">
   <div class="wc-restaurant-menu-product-inner">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://previews.123rf.com/images/fordzolo/fordzolo1506/fordzolo150600296/41026708-example-white-stamp-text-on-red-backgroud.jpg');"></div>
      <div class="details">
         <div class="header">
            <div class="name">Title</div>
            <div class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>21.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></bdi></span></div>
            <div class="buy-button">
               <button type="button" class="add icon" aria-label="Add to order">+</button>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="description">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And jsfiddle with all styles.
https://jsfiddle.net/qc5jnmyp/

Full plugin css:
https://jsfiddle.net/foutaLj7/

Comment: You want the "Some text" string under wc-restaurant-menu-product?

Comment: @MannyAlvarado I want to get this effect [link](https://prnt.sc/1uac81a)

Comment: This question need more detail

Comment: I want text below image. @MannyAlvarado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use styles according to need

Just put `border` on the outer container not on the the `image` .

Instead of putting border on class `.wc-restaurant-menu-product-inner` put border on class `.wc-restaurant-menu-product` like this :

```
.wc-restaurant-menu-product {
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(50 50 50 / 6%), 0 1px 3px rgb(50 50 50 / 6%);
  transition: border 0.2s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Also, if wanted text more near to image put `margin-top` value negative in `.description` .

```css
.wc-restaurant-menu-product {
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(50 50 50 / 6%), 0 1px 3px rgb(50 50 50 / 6%);
  transition: border 0.2s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wc-restaurant-menu-product .wc-restaurant-menu-product-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wc-restaurant-menu-product .image {
  flex: 0 0 110px;
  min-height: 110px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wc-restaurant-menu-product .details {
  flex: 1 1;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wc-restaurant-menu-product .header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -8px;
  z-index: auto;
}

.wc-restaurant-menu-product .header>div {
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.wc-restaurant-menu-product .description {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  color: #949494;
  line-height: 1.5;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wc-restaurant-menu-product" data-product-id="1" data-order-type="lightbox" data-quantity="1">
  <div class="wc-restaurant-menu-product-inner">
    <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://previews.123rf.com/images/fordzolo/fordzolo1506/fordzolo150600296/41026708-example-white-stamp-text-on-red-backgroud.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="details">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="name">Title</div>
        <div class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>21.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></bdi>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="buy-button">
          <button type="button" class="add icon" aria-label="Add to order">+</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="description">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's almost perfect, but if the description is too long it goes outside the border of .wc-restaurant-menu-product-inner div

Comment: That's why said make two flex container. It is more responsive

Comment: A simple solution will be putting `border` on the outer container not on the img one. Changed according to it

Comment: I tried your solution but still there's a problem. For example text overlaps the image: https://prnt.sc/1ubwzvk

Comment: Without margin-top it looks like this: https://prnt.sc/1ubyou7 and text comes out of the div on the mobile

Comment: I added full plugin css code without any changes, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Updated once again, still cannot find working solution.

Comment: Changed the answer and put `border` on  class `.wc-restaurant-menu-product` not on class `.wc-restaurant-menu-product-inner`

Comment: Its almost perfect, but description text still going out of .wc-restaurant-menu-product div

Comment: Plz share that code with changes . Code with solution applied and facing the problem with the same image you are facing problem

Comment: Thank u very much for help! I just removed `display: flex;` from `.wc-restaurant-menu-products` and everything is working excellent.

Comment: No problem, happy to help . And next time onwards provide code of your problem beforehand due to which you are facing the problem (**so that your problem can be reproduced**) . If any of the answer help you , you can upvote and accept

Answer (score 3):

With the current structure, just change some CSS properties and you can move the text to the bottom of the main div.

From your statement in the question, I got that you need to keep your description at the bottom of the div as you already said in the question, which means something like this:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmmYx.png)

If this is the case then just use `margin-top: auto;` on your description div.

[Here is the working example for you.](https://jsfiddle.net/cavmp64z/1/)

If you need it at the very bottom, then just remove the `padding-bottom` form details div or if you want something else. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put "description" class div outside of "wc-restaurant-menu-product".

I tried to paste the code but stackoverflow is not very effective at this.

You need to put `<div class="description">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</div>`

After "wc-restaurant-menu-product" closing tag

Comment: I tried this before but then the text is outside the div border. Check please: https://jsfiddle.net/qc5jnmyp/1/